# Visual Studio 2017 C#, debug async code, can't see local variables

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a solution composed of 2 projects (business logic and tests). I run test in debug to check what is wrong with business logic. 
The problem is that when I step through async method in business logic I can't see locals
[image]

[image]

But if I create the same method in my test class it works properly. So what's wrong with stepping thorough async method in referenced project?

Here is my test code
[image]

Comment: I don't think variables are automatically captured by the generated class, *unless they are being used across awaits*. Try adding this statement after await: `GC.KeepAlive(myVar);`

Comment: Shouldn't you break on line 53? 52 is where myVar is declared. So it wouldn't suprise me if it's not there.

Comment: What @Vanice told, if you are on the line 52 the variable has NOT been created, you must pass at least 1 line down to see that variable on debug mode

Comment: You'd get the same error in a normal method. That line hasn't executed yet so there's no `myVar` variable in scope.

Comment: Works okay when I try this in VS2017.  Be sure to keep VS updated, early releases had a lot of bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks a lot. But culprit in my case was ILMerge (in BusinessLogic project), which I forgot about, once I removed everything works fine!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you set the breakpoint at line 52. When the program reaches this line, it stops, *but it does not execute it*. So, `myVar` is not declared there. After running line 52 it will be declared and will be seen. Set your breakpoint at line 53.